# How to automatically refresh FlatList when data inserted in React Native?

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-native-flatlist

When adding data from GraphQL server, my FlatList doesn't update. I have tried refreshing and onRefresh, but I not quite sure how i will achieve it, hope someone can help me.

```
<View>
    <Query query={GET_ALL_RECIPES}>
      {({loading, data, error}) => (
        loading
          ? <ActivityIndicator />
          : (
            <FlatList
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
              extraData={this.state}
              data = {data ? data.allRecipes : []}
              renderItem = {({item})=>(
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
                  this.props.navigation.navigate('Details', {details: item})
                }}>
                  <Text style={styles.textConst}>Title: {item.title} </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.textConst}>Description: {item.description} </Text>
                  <Seperator />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
              />
            )
          )}
    </Query>
<View>
```

Comment: For updating UI based on data you should use state variable and setState method

Comment: Actually, there is one way for FlatList, someone helped me with onRefresh method

Answer (score 0):

You have to change:

`extraData={data}`

> By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state.selected changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.
>   [FlatList information here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

Comment: I wrote, but it didn't help

Comment: I have solved my problem with onRefresh method. Thank you for your time